# Indexed expression needs to be a type, mapping, or array

Tags: error

Just a quick question regarding an error in my code. I am getting a indexed expression needs to be a type, mapping, or array error for the code I posted below. I am very confused. I tried to create a mapping for this variable and it didnt seem to solve the problem. I also declared the variable in the global scope and still nothing changed. A bit confused here.

```
    //a function that allows a user to list their NFTs. No need to create a minting 
     function as ERC1155 implements the function already
     
     function listNFT(
     uint nftId, 
     uint priceOfNft
     ) 
     external 
   {
      require (balanceOf[msg.sender] > 0, "Not enough funds to list NFT");
      require (priceOfNft[nftId] >= 0, "Listing price must be greater than 0");

        if(balanceOf[msg.sender] <= 0){

           revert("Funds not sufficient enough to list NFT");
       }


        if(priceOfNft[nftId] <= 0){
        revert("Listing price must be greater than 0");
       }

       balanceOf[msg.sender] += amountOfNfts;
       tokenSupply.increment();

       tokenId = nftId;

       emit nftListed(tokenId, owner, priceOfNft);
    }
```

Comment: you have `uint priceOfNft` in function argument and `priceOfNft[nftId]` in the code, did you shadow some global variables with the same name ?

Comment: i actually fixed that issue. So the array that I define within the function is supposed to be a different name compared to the arguements?